# I keep getting 1064 error in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, database, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to create a table in phpmyadmin with the following

```
SQL : 

CREATE TABLE `umOrder`.`Bill` (
    `Id` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `userID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `product` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `quantity` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
    `price` DOUBLE(5) NOT NULL , 
    `date` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`(5))
  ) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

But keep getting this error :

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL , `date` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`Id`(5))) ENGINE =' at line 1

I don't really understand what the error mean ? any Idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key(id(5))` is suspect.  But you have another error as well:  `double` doesn't take a length argument.

The following should work:

```
CREATE TABLE `Bill` (
    `Id` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `userID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `product` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `quantity` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
    `price` DOUBLE NOT NULL , 
    `date` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
  ) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/097de) is a SQL Fiddle.

Note:  I don't think it is helpful to put length arguments after numeric types (other than `decimal`/`numeric`).  You might want to consider removing all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to assign the decimal for the double:

```
CREATE TABLE `umOrder`.`Bill` (
    `Id` INT (5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userID` VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    `product` VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    `quantity` INT (3) NOT NULL,
    `price` DOUBLE (5,2) NOT NULL,
    `date` VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

Answer (score 0):

"double" doesn't take a length argument, just like Gordon Linoff said above.

I got almost exactly the same problem.

Then I got rid of the length for double, and everything is fine now.